# Absolute of a function equal to zero

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

How would I prove the following theorem:

if $\sup \{ |f (x)| :x>0\} = 0$

this implies

$|f (x)| = 0$ for all real number $x$.

Comment: You need to edit your question.

Comment: @John what I need to prove is that if supremum of an absolute function over positive real line is equal to zero, this implies that the absolute of that function itself is zero over whole real line.

Comment: I have just edited your question, is that what you are asking for?

Comment: Yes, I want to prove this. The extra information about f (x) is that it is continuous on positive real line.

Answer (score 0):

What do you know about $f$? The statement is certainly not true for continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$. A counter-example:
$$
f(x) = |x| -x
$$

Comment: $f$ is continuous on $0$ to onward.

Comment: In the case of function taken as $ f (x) = |x| - x $, for negative x , your assumption that $sup (f) = 0$ can be true in any case, so $sup (f) = 0$ condition is basically making your domain shrink.

Comment: @user157336: Sorry I don't understand. The function $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=0$ for all $x>0$ and $f(-1)=2$. How is this not a counter example to the statement you want to prove?

Comment: Yes indeed. The true statement is:

if $\sup \{ |f (x)| :x>0\} = 0$ 

this implies

$|f (x)| = 0$ for all real number $x > 0$.